# Error in app.config

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I'm getting following error in app.config on compilation in Visual Studio. How do I resolve such errors, please?

```
Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x13 is illegal in XML documents.
```

Comment: @john no, 0xD is `\r` (which is decimal 13).  0x13 is some control character I never used...

Comment: Try editing the file with a different editor, e.g. Notepad++, it may help you locate and replace or remove the character.

Answer (score 4):

0x13 is a control character (XOFF)(Device Control 3) that is not printable. [ASCII Table](https://www.systutorials.com/4670/ascii-table-and-ascii-code/).

Try to open the XML in a good text editor, e.g. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.7.html). Notepad++ has the option to show all characters, even not printable ones (View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters).

Then find and delete the offending character.